# Lumen Laravel V 10 : Builder::relatedTo(): Argument #1 ($subject) must be of type string, null given

Tags: authentication, jwt, lumen

I'm having trouble when I want to generate jwt auth tokens with Laravel 10 lumens
'
Error msg : Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Builder::relatedTo(): Argument #1 ($subject) must be of type string, null given, called in D:\Kuliah LJ\TA\masterapi\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Providers\JWT\Lcobucci.php on line 163

my step is to configure jwt like this:

1. Install "composer require tymon/jwt-auth"
2. activate and add service to bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();

$app->configure('app');
$app->configure('jwt');
$app->configure('auth');

$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider::class);
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);
```

3. Generate jwt secret = php artisan jwt:secret
4. file config/auth.php

```
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => \App\Models\AppUser::class
        ]
    ]
];
```

5. Then my user model is like this

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class AppUser extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, JWTSubject
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'Auth.AppUser';

    protected $fillable = [
        'Username', 'Email','Phone','FullName','role',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

In logincontroller I use code like this

```
$user = AppUser::where('username', $request->username)->first();
        if($user)
        {
            if( Crypt::decrypt($user->password) == $request->password)
            {
                
                $token = \Auth::login($user);
                $resp = [
                    'response' => [
                        'token'=> $token  
                    ],
                    'metadata' => [
                        'message' => 'OK',
                        'code'    => 200
                    ]
                ];

                return response()->json($resp);
            }else{

                $resp = [
                    'metadata' => [
                        'message' => 'Username or Password Not Correct',
                        'code'    => 401
                    ]
                ];

                return response()->json($resp, 401);
            }
        }

        $resp = [
            'metadata' => [
                'message' => 'Username Atau Password Tidak Sesuai',
                'code'    => 401
            ]
        ];

        return response()->json($resp, 401);
    }
```

I thought it was supposed to return the token when logged in, but instead got an error

Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Builder::relatedTo(): Argument #1 ($subject) must be of type string, null given, called in D:\Kuliah LJ\TA\masterapi\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Providers\JWT\Lcobucci.php on line 163

Please help, and thank you

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was that the model's primary key column name was not default, i.e. it was `user_id` instead of `id`.

Specifying that in model did the trick:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

or you can just return it directly in (not tested, but should work):

```
public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return "user_id";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me identify the issue with JWT login.